# Check each class in a li list and .remove all others

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

```
<ul class="logos">
       <div class="row">
            <li class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 7676327">
                  content
            </li>
            <li class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 7676325">
                 Content
            </li>
            <li class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 7676327">
                 Content
            </li>
            <li class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 7676326">
                 Content
            </li>
      </div>
</ul>
```

I want to loop though the above list of `<li>` items and find class `.7676327` then I like to remove all other classes in the list

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Sounds great; what have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service; we are here to answer specific, directed questions about your coding problems. Consider reviewing [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and editing your question appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [.not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) selector to target all the elements with the above use case.

```
// Select all the elements without the class 7676327 and remove them
$('.logos li').not('.7676327').remove();
```

```js
$('.logos li').not('.7676327').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="logos">
       <div class="row">
            <li class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 7676327">
                  content
            </li>
            <li class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 7676325">
                 Content
            </li>
            <li class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 7676327">
                 Content
            </li>
            <li class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 7676326">
                 Content
            </li>
      </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by below code.

```js
$('ul.logos li.7676327').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="logos">
       <div class="row">
            <li class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 7676327">
                  content
            </li>
            <li class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 7676325">
                 Content
            </li>
            <li class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 7676327">
                 Content
            </li>
            <li class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 7676326">
                 Content
            </li>
      </div>
</ul>
```